# Many TCP connections localajaxchat <=> 1e100

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I don't get that: as soon as I open a Webpage, whether it's with Firefox or Chrome (I didn't test IE), there are tons of TCP connections between "localajaxchat" and a supposed google ("1e100") domain.

I've already read [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/75841/what-is-1e100-net-and-why-do-i-have-tcp-ports-open-to-it), but my problem seems strange because there are so many TCP connections *for only one page*... I don't get it.

(Edit) : it seems that "localajaxchat" is looking through the history of the browsers and tries to connect, this means it tries to connect to all the ("1e100") domain (= all the verifications sent to google), but to the other websites as well (for example in the grab screen it's generali).

I'm stuck and the big problem is that it slows down the network.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using something called [AJAX Chat](https://blueimp.net/ajax/)?
Can you try stopping it for a while to check?
Your TVPView snapshot shows local connections,

```
firefox pid 5424 ==> local olivier-hton:43175 to remote localhost:43174
firefox pid 5424 ==> local localhost:43174    to olivier-hton:43175
```

So, you have a lot of internal communication on the machine.

When you say your network slows down, do you mean the network activity on your PC slows down?
or, do you have a local-network with multiple PCs which seems to slow down? (I guess not)

---

Update:

- Well, your snapshot shows a lot of connections happening internally.
  This may not be part of the high connection syndrome you describe.
  But, it would be useful to know what is causing them.
- To check what is the cause of the outbound connections,
  one more way would be to start a [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) session and capture these packets.
  Looking at the communication data might help figure what is going on.
- If you suspect host-file corruption by some malware (phishing),
  you could also install and run [Spybot Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/spybotsd/index.html) once.

Comment: My webserver is off. It has been off for more than 8 months... I did understand one thing: my computer is looking for the 192.168.0.14 and in the host file, the first one is localajaxchat. But that doesn't explain the rest: why so *many connexions*, and if it's for memory saving, why do they duplicate for **each** tab?

Answer (score 1):

The "local address" is the one at *your* end, which means that either `localajaxchat.com` is configured as your own computer's hostname, or that one of your computer's IP addresses reverses to it (rDNS).

In other words, it's *you*.

---

Now the "tons" of HTTP connections is very likely to be simply ["persistent connections"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) kept by your browsers for performance reasons. It's a normal thing to see.

The connections might be opened by Chrome for its "phishing protection", self-update, or search suggestions; they might also be simple HTTP requests made when a page has Google's AdSense or Analytics embedded. I doubt they could slow down the network a lot: your screenshot only shows the connections being *open*, but that does not mean any data is being transferred. The browser just hasn't "hung up" yet.

Comment: You are right. My computer is looking for the 192.168.0.14 and in the host file, the first one is localajaxchat. If it's for browsers for performance reasons, why do they duplicate for **each** tab? This would consume far more ressources... I don't get that

Comment: @Oliver, Actually, keeping persistent connections as `grawity` describes, has value. Compare that with the number of connection attempts the browser would have to make if it kept closing the connections. It would appear like a bad move when you have too many tabs open (or your browser is doing too many things). But, you have to look at the comparative condition without persistent-connections to appreciate the difference.

Comment: @Olivier, when you visit a website nowadays, a lot more domains are contacted than the one the page of the website is on. Content off-loading, advertisements, analytics, and so on... For each domain a connection is made and this connection is as nik said persistent so that when you go to the next page it doesn't have to initiate a new connection. Duplicates might be because tabs are separate processes, but aren't a big impact on performance...

Answer (score 0):

Your computer name seems to be olivier-hton, the reason you see localajaxchat.com is because it is configured to be the name of 127.0.0.1 or a secondary IP you have, which is the IP you should see if you disable resolving in that program.

The other part of your question has already been answered in
[What is 1e100.net and why do I have TCP ports open to it?](https://superuser.com/questions/75841/what-is-1e100-net-and-why-do-i-have-tcp-ports-open-to-it)

Comment: In the question, I've said I had already read the topic you mention, but thanks for the answer. I did understand one thing: my computer is looking for the 192.168.0.14 and in the host file, the first one is localajaxchat. But that doesn't explain the rest: why so *many connexions*, and if it's for memory saving, why do they duplicate for **each** tab?